# Use stopPropagation() in $(document).on(...)

Tags: html, jquery, jquery-events

I would add some "Li" tags in my page **dynamically**.

**Each "Li" have some codes like this:**

```
<li id="file-1000">
    <a target="_blank" href="pack.jpg" style="display: block;" class="pirobox_gall first last">
       <img alt="" src="pack_thumb.jpg" class="attached">
       <i style="display: none;" class="icon-close2" id="delIcon-1000"></i>
    </a>
</li>
```

**Result:**

[image]

---

Events:

**1) I bind some events to the "a" and "i" tags like this:**

```
$(document)
    .on('mouseenter',
        '#file-1000',
        function () {
            $('#delIcon-1000').fadeIn(200);
        })
    .on('mouseleave',
        '#file-1000',
        function () {
            $('#delIcon-1000').fadeOut(200);
        })
    .on('click',
        '#delIcon-1000',
        function () {
            alert('Close btn is clicked');
        });
```

**2) An other hand, the "a" tag have other assigned events on its click event (by a jQuery image slide plugin: piroBox)**

---

So when I click on the image, I see a nice popup of my image (as a large picture) but when I click the Delete button I see the large image + "Close btn is clicked" message" together.

**I want prevent "a" tag click event (parent event) when I click the Delete button (when I click it's child).**

I know using `stopPropagation()` is a solution but it does not work here and I don't know how can I use it in the `$(document).on(....)` method.

---

**Edit:**
I tried some answers but they failed and the result is like this:

[image]

**Above Black Frame is >>** a popup box for showing larger picture (I want prevent opening this frame)

Comment: Why are you doing `$('#file-1000').selector`?  Why not just `'#file-1000'`?

Comment: yes, Your opinion is correct. i changed it.

Comment: You can't stop the propagation of an event that has already propagated to the document.(well, you can, but it doesn't do what you would expect since there isn't any propagation going on at that point) You need to instead ensure event.target matches the selector.

Comment: @KevinB, how can i override onclick event of my "piroBox" plugin and check event.target??? how can i prevent its default behavior??? i dont want modify the pirobox plugin. my question is base on this problem. (pirobox: http://www.pirolab.it/pirobox/)

Comment: You can't if the piroBox's event handling is bound directly to the element and not the document. (I haven't inspected the plugin to see if it is indeed doing that, but that's what most plugins do)

Comment: If piroBox using jquery to bind event, you could remove it using $._data(elem,"events") array

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### edit

## ***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/YZ7UW/1/)***

It was brought to my attention that the deprecated approach first listed will in fact not work here. That is 100% correct, sorry for missing that. In fact, that scenario seems rather complex! How can you, from the outside, manage to prevent a click action which takes place prior to yours which is also attached to another element? Well, I am not sure entirely what the "best practice" is. I came up with this approach though.

Iterate from the element up the dom tree looking for click events. Collect those click events. Iterate through all of the handlers collected, and then overload them to screen for your element if the event was based on your element.

*Initial Setup*

```
$("#file-1000").click(function(e){
 console.log(e);
 alert("some other click"); 
});

$(document)
.on('mouseenter',
    $('#file-1000').selector,
    function () {
        $('#delIcon-1000').fadeIn(200);
    })
.on('mouseleave',
    $('#file-1000').selector,
    function () {
        $('#delIcon-1000').fadeOut(200);
    })
.on('click',
    $('#delIcon-1000').selector,
    function (e) {
        alert('Close btn is clicked');
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

*Implementation of iteration as described above*

```
function ProtectClick(element){
 var handlers = [];
 var elCopy = element;
 do{
  var handler = jQuery._data( elCopy, "events" );
  if( handler != void 0 && handler.click != void 0){
   handlers.push({el: elCopy, handle: handler.click});
  }
  elCopy = elCopy.parentNode;
 }while( elCopy );

 for( var h in handlers ){
  (function(i){
   for( var cur in handlers[i].handle ){
    (function(n){
     var handlerCopy = handlers[i].handle[n].handler;
     var $sourced;
     if( handlers[i].handle[n].selector ){
      $sourced = $(handlers[i].handle[n].selector);
     }else{
      $sourced = $(handlers[i].el);
     }
     handlers[i].handle[n].handler = function(e){
      if( $sourced.is(element) || element != e.target )handlerCopy(e);
     };       
    })(cur);
   }
  })(h);
 }
}
```

*Call*

```
ProtectClick($('#delIcon-1000')[0]);
```

---

## *deprecated*

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/arVYB/)***

I believe what you were looking for is `preventDefault`

```
$(document)
.on('mouseenter',
    '#file-1000',
    function () {
        $('#delIcon-1000').fadeIn(200);
    })
.on('mouseleave',
    '#file-1000',
    function () {
        $('#delIcon-1000').fadeOut(200);
    })
.on('click',
    '#delIcon-1000',
    function (e) {
        alert('Close btn is clicked');
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

Comment: I don't think this will work in the actual situation described.  `preventDefault` is simply preventing the link from going to the page it defines.  The described situation is that there are additional click handlers attached which show a larger image.  `preventDefault` will not affect this behavior.  For example:  http://jsfiddle.net/arVYB/2/

Comment: @JamesMontagne,  Your opinion is correct. this code prevent link but the image popup is open yet. this is not correct answer.

Comment: @JamesMontagne - Thanks for pointing that out, I believe I missed it when I first posted this answer. I just posted an edit which handles your fiddle's situation (and hopefully more generic situations as well).

Comment: @RAM - At that point it was not correct, please see the edited version and tell me if that works in your situation.

Comment: @TravisJ, i will try your new answer 10 hours later (after my working time). but where i must use ProtectClick($('#delIcon-1000')[0])???

Comment: @TravisJ, your answer is prefect. but i have a problem yet: when i call ProtectClick function after your suggestion codes (any where) it does not working but if i call it by Firebug console command line it works!!!

Comment: @TravisJ, if i use this code it works:   setTimeout(function(){ProtectClick($('#delIcon-1000')[0]);},3000);

Answer (score 0):

you could try with this

```
$('html').on('click', '#file-1000', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();
  alert('Close btn is clicked');
});
```

e.stopPropagation is ejecuted.

Great day.